# How to get an ENV var available in project which uses Android.mk

Tags: android, makefile, environment-variables

I have an Android project which uses Android.mk files for the setup. I would like to introduce Build Variants to the project and based on a build var such as BUILD_BRAND to perform some UI changes.

My case is:
I have BUILD_BRAND exported on my Ubuntu in the `.bashrc`.
If I `echo $BUILD_BRAND` I would get the value printed in the terminal.

I also do `$(warning $(BUILD_BRAND))` and I can see during the build the value is printed so it is available.

But when I try to do `System.getEnv("BUILD_BRAND");` in an activity, a null is returned.

The question is how to make this value under BUILD_BRAND to become globally available to the project.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the solution was to use `SystemProperties.get("the.property.name")`.

The `"the.property.name"` was set in the Makefile.mk located in the core.

I also find out that I can export ENV vars to the project during build time using the same Makefile.mk.

N.B - You can't access an env var during runtime directly using `System.getEnv()` !